# get index path for editing row in prepareForSegue?

Tags: ios, xcode, uipopovercontroller

I am presenting a popover from a `UITableView` and using the `prepareForSegue` method as discussed in In WWDC 2014 "`View Controller` Advancements in iOS8"

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

UINavigationController * nvc = segue.destinationViewController;
UIPopoverPresentationController * pvc = nvc.popoverPresentationController;
pvc.delegate = self;
}

- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller
{
return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```

Problem is, I need to pass a value from the edited row to the popover. Is there a way to do this cleanly such as (I know it doesn't exist, but)

```
[self.myTableView indexPathForEditingRow];
```

I tried

```
[self.myTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

but this returns the first row in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check, who your `sender` is. If it is a cell, you have all you need.
If not, you need to make a property and remember the index path in `didSelectCell` method of the `tableView` delegate.

Comment: Yep, thats pretty much nailed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling performSegueWithIdentifier from the table view, you can send the indexPath along for the ride.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"identifier" sender:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath];
```

Then you can call prepareForSegue, you will need an exposed method or property to set the indexPath on the popover

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"identifier"])
     {
         UINavigationController * nvc = segue.destinationViewController;
         UIPopoverPresentationController * pvc = nvc.popoverPresentationController;
         //added property
         pvc.indexPath = indexPath;
         pvc.delegate = self;
     }
}
```

Comment: That's actually dangerous, if there will be more segues from the same controller.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
NSLog(@"Riga selezionata: %ld",(long)[indexPath row]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `UITableView` extension:

```
extension UITableView {

    var indexPathForEditingRow: NSIndexPath? {
        return indexPathsForEditingRows.first
    }

    var indexPathsForEditingRows: [NSIndexPath] {
        return visibleCells.flatMap { cell -> NSIndexPath? in
            guard let indexPath = indexPathForCell(cell) where cell.editingStyle != .None else {
                return nil
            }
            return indexPath
        }
    }

}
```